# How to charge your suit in space engineers?

Tags: space-engineers

How do you charge your suit in space engineers?
I can't use the welder because apparently, my suit has no energy.
I tried placing Uranium into the nuclear reactor but, i still can't use the welder.

Comment: Dying also restore energy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To charge your suit in Space Engineers, go to a [medical room's](http://spaceengineers.wikia.com/wiki/Medical_Room) terminal and hold `T`
Obviously, you have to be producing energy in order to charge it.

Your suit will also charge while you are sitting in the [cockpit or any of its variants](http://spaceengineers.wikia.com/wiki/Cockpit) or [passenger seats](http://spaceengineers.wikia.com/wiki/Passenger_Seat) of a powered ship or station.

Comment: So if I got discharged in the 3rd mission where you have to build the battery to get the base online, I am stuck right? Is there any trick to get charged?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the answer by @user9239425 (using a healing terminal). Your suit is also charged when you are in the cockpit of a powered ship.